# Baked lightmap errors in adjacent polygons

Tags: unity, lightmap

Everything seems to work great, but in some parts of my model I get shadows like this

[image]

If I look at the light map, it looks bad:

[image]

What is the best approach to solve this issue?

Here my light settings:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your lightmapping settings?

Comment: @DMGregory Sure, I've updated the question

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the lightmap resolution, padding, and compression settings?

Comment: yes, I've increased resolution and padding, but I always get weird results at those connections